# Constructing objects from database queries in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm fairly new to android but I have some J2EE experience. I am working on an android application and my model makes use of the composite pattern, and in addition some of the objects will contain a list of other objects. I understand when dealing with mobile apps, I won't have as much memory available and when looking at my design, I will probably end up loading a lot of objects in memory with my current models when I'm querying the sqllite database. So my question is for people who have worked in both worlds, did you have to make changes in the way you deal with objects (how you populate them from the database etc...) to make the application run faster?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really. You can use SQLite or [db4o](http://www.db4o.com/android/) if you prefer a non relational dbms.

Just read the best practices for [performance](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/performance.html) and [responsiveness](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html) and you'll be alright. Don't worry about performance issues until you find them in your app. You can always optimize later.